# TypeScript compile-time heap overflow or how to resolve circular (infinitely deep) type error

Tags: typescript, generics, compiler-errors, circular-reference, typescript-generics

I am designing a strongly typed, type checking utility library. `TypeScript 3.4.1` introduced new compile-time errors into my project.
I have a `Schema` type that describes the shape of some target type. And I have `UnpackSchema<TSchema extends Schema>` type that expands to the type described by `Schema` (e.g. runtime schema object `{ ids: ['number'] }` would describe static `{ ids: number[] }` type).

I have a circular type reference issue in `UnpackSchema<>` type body. Since hacks with extending interfaces don't help here, I use code generation to throw in many definitions of `UnpackSchema<>` that reference themselves linearly until they hit `never` type at the deepest level. Further, I'll show only a small part of `UnpackSchema<>` definition and even when I generate 3 instances of `UnpackSchema<>` `tsc` hangs for a while and fails to compile my code with heap overflow. So I am desperate to strongly type my project as even code generation fails. **Is it `tsc` performance issue and/or is there any workaround I can use to avoid code generation here?**

My simplified definition of `UnpackSchema<>` is the following (I won't show `Schema<>` definition as it is complex and out of the scope):

```
export type UnpackSchema<TSchema extends Schema> = (    
    TSchema extends 'string' ? string :
    // ... a lot more cases
    TSchema extends SchemaObj ? UnpackSchemaObject<TSchema> :
    never
);

type SchemaObj = Record<any, Schema>;

// Circular type reference error here
export type UnpackSchemaObject<TObj extends SchemaObj> = MarkUndefinedKeyAsOptional<{
    [TKey in keyof TObj]: UnpackSchema<TObj[TKey]>;
}>;

// adds ? modifier if object's property value contains `undefined` type
type MarkUndefinedKeyAsOptional<TObj> = (
    & TObj[Exclude<keyof TObj, GetUndefinedKeysUnion<TObj>>]
    & Partial<Pick<TObj, GetUndefinedKeysUnion<TObj>>>
);

type GetUndefinedKeysUnion<TObj> = {
    [TKey in keyof TObj]: TObj[TKey] extends undefined ? TKey : never; 
}[keyof TObj];
```

Heap overflow report (when compiling project with `tsc`):

> [image: Report screenshot]

Comment: [Microsoft/TypeScript#30663](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30663) might be relevant?

Comment: @jcalz Might be, thanks for pointing out